# R Global Function to Clear Workspace and Dump Storage

Tags: r, function, global-functions

I was hoping to make a global function that would clear my workspace and dump my memory. I called my function "cleaner" and want it to execute the following code:

```
remove(list = ls())
gc()
```

I tried making the function in the global environment but when I run it, the console just prints the text of the function. In my function file to be sourced:

```
cleaner <- function(){
    remove(list = ls())
    gc()
    #I tried adding return(invisible()) to see if that helped but no luck
}

cleaner()
```

Even when I make the function in the script I want it to run (cutting out any potential errors with sourcing), the storage dump seems to work, but it still doesn't clear the workspace.

[image]

Comment: cleaner()? Or cleanerFile()?

Comment: Oops, I attached the wrong screenshot. Same result though.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, it doesn't do what you want. The best way to do what you want is to restart R, but I don't know of a good way to run a command line that does it. In RStudio, you would use the shortcut Ctrl (or Cmd) + Shift + F10, or click on Session -> Restart R

Comment: When I do the Ctrl + Shift + F10 and it restarts I still have all of my variables, df, functions etc in my environment. Googling this shows that's due to auto-saving my .RData, which I would rather not disable. I have a keyboard shortcut for clearing workspace, but I wondered if it was possible to make one command that also does gc() since there is no keyboard shortcut for that. It's two lines of code so not too much work at all, but now I am just wondering why my function above doesn't work.

Comment: Likely because you are saving .RData, which I recommend you don't do. https://onunicornsandgenes.blog/2017/04/02/using-r-dont-save-your-workspace/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts about this: Your code does not delete all objects, to also remove the hidden ones use

```r
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
```

There is also the command `gctorture()` which *provokes garbage collection on (nearly) every memory allocation* (as the man page said). It's intended for R developers to ferret out memory protection bugs:

```r
cleaner <- function(){
    # Turn it on
    gctorture(TRUE)

    # Clear workspace
    rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE, envir=sys.frame(-1)),
       envir = sys.frame(-1))

    # Turn it off (important or it gets very slow)
    gctorture(FALSE)
}
```

If this procedure is used within a function, there is the following problem: Since the function has its own stack frame, only the objects within this stack frame are deleted. They still exist outside. Therefore, it must be specified separately with `sys.frame(-1)` that only the higher-level stack frame should be considered. The variables are then only deleted within the function that calls `cleaner()` and in `cleaner` itself when the function is exited.

But this also means that the function may only be called from the top level in order to function correctly (you can use `sys.frames()` which lists all higher-level stack frames to build something that also avoids this problem if really necessary)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the hidden files.

Your code works great and I can run it as 3 lines, but is there really no way to make a function like 

cleaner <- function (){
     your 3 lines from above
}

then call cleaner()?